# Independence of multivariate random variables

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory

Let $X=(X_1,X_2,...,X_n)$ be an independent multivariate random variable, i.e.
$$
F_X(x_1, x_2,...,x_n)=\prod_{i=1}^{n}F_{X_i}(x_i)
$$
This implies that if we take 2 components $X_i, X_j$, these are independent as well:
$$
F_{(X_i, X_j)}(x,y)=F_{X_i}(x) \cdot F_{X_j}(y)
$$
I need to prove that the reverse statement is not true, i.e this is false:
$$
F_{(X_i, X_j)}(x,y)=F_{X_i}(x) \cdot F_{X_j}(y) \implies F_X(x_1, x_2,...,x_n)=\prod_{i=1}^{n}F_{X_i}(x_i)
$$

A theoretical proof or a counter-example are both acceptable.
Thanks, András

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard counter example is to take $X,Y,Z$ such that $Z=X\oplus Y$, where $\oplus$ denotes the ex-or operation. Each pair is independent, however any two completely determine the third.